# undefined length constraint while reading string input in c++

Tags: string, string-length

while reading a string input in c++ console, I'm facing an issue with the max length of string that can be read from console , I can't read a string of length more than 4094.

using following command: cin>>s //s being string variable.

opensource c++ compiler version used: dev c++5.11

Please help!!

Comment: Is your "string" a `std::string s;` or a `char s[4095];`?

Comment: declaring the variable as:  string s; and then reading the string from console in s with no prior constraint defined by me.

Comment: It's a [Windows console limitation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830473).

Comment: @Bob__ That's about the command-line length limit, not the entered prompt limit.